# Knockout- foreach over nested array- not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js

I have observableArray which its elements- are arrays.
I need over by foreach, but I need to show each time only the last element of the observableArray- i.e.- the last array.
For example:
My observable array is:

```
 self.treeLists = [
         [{id:1, name:'tar'}, {id:9, name:'se'}, {id:5, name:'tzav'}],
         [{id:4, name:'sus'}, {id:8, name:'par'}],
         [{id:7, name:'tal'}, {id:6, name:'med'}]
];
```

So I need to show only the third array- [{id:7, name:'tal'}, {id:6, name:'med'}]

Here is My HTML, but it cause problem!!!
It read it like I tried to over on the observalbeArray and show **its** elements...

```
    <div data-bind="if: treeLists().length>1">
                    <div data-bind="foreach: treeLists()[treeLists().length-1]">
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <div class="organizationTreeItem">
                                <img class="floutR" data-bind="attr: {src: $parent.global.imagesManager.plusblue}, click:$parent.itemClickPathMode" />
                                <span data-bind="text:$data.name"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

The error-message is:

**Unhandled exception at line 1981, column 17 in http://localhost/myProj/Scripts/knockout-2.3.0.debug.js
0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'OrgName' is undefined**

You can see the situation when I debugged, see the picture:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$data` contains the objects of the last array, for example: `{id:7, name:'tal'}`

In HTML you're binding to `$data.OrgName`, but OrgName is not a member of the bound object, so it indeed is undefined, like the exception mentions. Did you mean to bind to "name"?

```
<span data-bind="text:name"></span>
```

Also `treeLists` is not an observableArray yet. Have a look at the following [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kv7s202z/).

Comment: Yes, it is only typing mistake. But the problem is exist

Comment: Maybe it's because treeLists isn't declared as an observableArray? Have a look at the following fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kv7s202z/